# UCWA Skype for Business Online API Authentication - 403 Forbidden Applications Resource

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm following this guide (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread) to attempt and authenticate and create a Skype App.

My goal is to create a Skype Meeting via the API and generate an Online Meeting URL.

I'm able to get as far as generating the Applications Resource URL.

When I attempt POST to the URL I receive a 403 Forbidden error. Looks like there might be an issue with the token? However I am using the token in earlier requests to get the App URL.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Post Request:

```
POST https://webpool.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer (edited)
x-ms-request-root-id: a9c17f66-46d761cf7325d6a7
x-ms-request-id: |a9c17f66-46d761cf7325d6a7.6.
Request-Id: |a9c17f66-46d761cf7325d6a7.6.1.
Content-Length: 96
Host: webpoolblu0b11.infra.lync.com

{ UserAgent = UCWA Samples, EndpointId = f87e1d57-83a4-4f9b-aac7-00f05f440637, Culture = en-US }
```

Post Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Permissions:

[image]

Comment: Which scopes have you requested? It would also help to have the HTTP request that results in the `403`.

Comment: Hey Marc, sorry for just now getting back to this. I've updated the raw HTTP Post request where I'm Posting to /applications URL I receive back. I'm not explicitly requesting any scopes as I'm retrieving the access token via ADAL. I'm using that access token to retrieve the /applications URL earlier on, so I wouldn't think that would be a problem?

Comment: Sorry, I meant scopes in the larger context of "permissions" rather than an actual `scope` attribute. When you register your app in AD you had to provide a list of permissions. These were really what I was after.

Comment: No problem! Updated with an image of permissions. Only used delegate. Do I need application level?

Comment: I assume `webpoolblu0b11.infra.lync.com` was what the autodiscovery process returned? Have you tried opening the bearer token to make sure the scopes you need are showing up? If not, you can do that by pasting the token into http://jwt.io.

Comment: Yes that is the URL "scp": "Contacts.ReadWrite Conversations.Initiate Conversations.Receive Meetings.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite" Are those not right?

Comment: What Resource URL should I be using when requesting a token? I first request then I get a redirect URL. I then hit that and use that as my Resource URL, which ends up being https://webdir0b.online.lync.com that's the URL that finally returns a successful applications url. Should I then be generating another token? Or just re-use

Comment: @MarcLaFleur any additional thoughts here? could provide more information if needed. thanks!

Comment: Still no solution here...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out. I wasn't serializing the JSON properly. Below is a fixed snippet:

```
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var jsonObject = new
            {
                UserAgent = "UCWA Samples",
                EndpointId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Culture = "en-US"
            };

            var createMeetingPostData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

            var content = new StringContent(createMeetingPostData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var data = await client.PostAsync(appUrlData.appUrl, content);
```